# Are marital relations on Friday nights a "double mitzvah"?

Tags: oneg-shabbat, leil-shabbat, sexuality

An uncle of mine once told me that a rabbi told him that having marital relations on Friday nights is a "double mitzvah," presumably because one would be fulfilling both the obligation to have pleasure (oneg shabbat) and the obligation to be fruitful and multiply (piryah verivryah = procreation).  Where is the source for considering this a double mitzvah, doing two mitzvot b'vat achat?

Comment: What is a "double mitzvah"? Are you asking whether the act constitutes a fulfillment of _pirya v'rivya_, whether it fulfills _oneg shabas_, or whether it is possible to perform two _mitzvos_ with a single act?

Comment: But what if a child is created?? We are not allowed to create on Shabbat!

Comment: @Chaya - Some halakhic authorities (Ben Ish Chai, Rav Kook?) forbid saying *birkat ha-ilanot* on shabbat because it is being *boreir* the nitzotzot ha-kedoshim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 280:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=68)

> תשמיש המטה מתענוגי שבת הוא, לפיכך עונת תלמידי חכמים הבריאים מליל שבת לליל שבת.‏
>   Marital relations are among the delights ("oneg") of Shabbat, and therefore the time for marital relations for a healthy Torah scholar is from Friday night to Friday night. (translation mine)

So the two mitzvot are Oneg Shabat and Onah. If you want to throw in Peru Urvu, all the better!